# access_token without custom claims, with claims still returned from userinfo

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

**Tl;dr:** How can I prevent custom claims from appearing in the access token and only be returned when you call the `userinfo` endpoint?

I have an IdentityServer4 (using `authorization_code` grant type) where, on successful 3rd party authentication, I get some additional information on the user. I store these as claims, sign in the user to the IS4 service and adding those claims to the user. The claims are hooked up to an identity resource scope called "custom"

```
var myUser = some3rdParty.GetUserData();

Claim[] claims = {
    new Claim("custom.value1", myUser.Custom1),
    new Claim("custom.value2", myUser.Custom2)
};

await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent("myOidcProviderIS4", myUser.Id, myUser.Id, myUser.Fullname));
await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    myUser.Id,
    myUser.Fullname,
    new AuthenticationProperties(),
    claims);
```

Now, when I retrieve an access token, it does not contain these custom claims, but it contains the "custom" scope. The next step would be to call the `userinfo` endpoint to get these custom claims. However, by default, calls to the `userinfo` endpoint, does *not* include these custom claims.

I therefore created an `IProfileService` to copy the claims into `IssuedClaims`:

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
         List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();

        foreach (IdentityResource identityResource in context.RequestedResources.IdentityResources)
        {
            foreach (string userClaim in identityResource.UserClaims)
            {
                var claim = context.Subject.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == userClaim);
                if (claim != null)
                {
                    claims.Add(claim);
                }
            }
        }

        if (claims.Any())
        {
            context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Now when I call the `userinfo` endpoint, my custom claims are visible.

But after inspecting the access token I could see that my custom claims are visible there as well. I feel that this is a bit redundant as you (in this case) don't really have to make a call to `userinfo`.

I made the following observations if I do not have my custom `IProfileService` implementation (The class is still there, but with just an empty method):

- `context.Subject.Claims` contains the custom claims when calling the `token` endpoint, but it does not contain the custom claims when called from `userinfo`.
- The `PersistedGrants` table in the database has a `Data` column which also contains the custom tokens.

So the question still is: How can I prevent my custom claims from appearing in the access token and only be returned when you call the `userinfo` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably a configuration issue.

Client has to be defined with 2 allowed scopes:

- `IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId`
- "custom"

```cs
new Client
{
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        "custom"
    },
    // etc...
```

And then on the client configure `ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken;`:

```cs
.AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
{
    o.Scope.Clear();
    o.Scope.Add("openid");
    o.Scope.Add("custom");
    o.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken;
    // etc...
```

Comment: My client already has the `custom` added to allowed scopes, and I'm using `authorization_code` grant type, so I can only use "code" as a response type.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the caller is for `/userinfo` (I assume this is what the original intention was behind including that property):

```
 if (context.Caller == IdentityServerConstants.ProfileDataCallers.UserInfoEndpoint)
        { 
            //custom logic to add requested claims 
            context.AddRequestedClaims(claims);
        }
```

Comment: If I'm not doing `GetProfileDataAsync`when the caller is `/token`, then the custom data is not available anymore when caller is `/userinfo`

Comment: I don't understand you, all you should need to do is wrap your logic within `GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)` to conditionally execute only when the `/userinfo` endpoint is called.

Comment: If I do that my custom data won't be returned when `/userinfo` endpoint is called. It is only returned if the logic is executed on both `/token` and `/userinfo`

Comment: Its the exact opposite of what should happen, how are you testing this? Can you check the value of `context.Caller` when going through your flow? It should be different when it is called twice.

Comment: The first time the method is invoked `context.Caller == "AccessToken" (I don't remember the exact const they use right now). During this first time `context.Subject.Claims` contains all my claims. If I do not move them over to `context.IssuedClaims` they will not be available the second time the method is invoked (when `context.Caller == UserInfoEndPoint`)

Comment: You are missing this line I think then `context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);` - add this outside the conditional logic

Comment: I tried adding `.AddRequestedClaims()` to `GetProfileDataAsync()`, and it had no effect. when `context.Caller == "ClaimsProviderAccessToken"` then `context.Subject.Claims` contains all my custom data. When `context.Caller == "UserInfoEndpoint"`then `context.Subject.Claims` contains only the `sub` claim. If I use `AddRequestedClaims()` together with my code, I'm back to where I started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check ApiResource configuration. Whatever claims you add in *UserClaims* property of *ApiResource* configuration, those claims will appear in access token. e.g

```
 public IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
        {
            return new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("api1")
                {
                    UserClaims = new[] { "CustomClaim1", "CustomClaim2"},
                }, 
             }
        }
```

In above code, access code will contain *CustomClaim1* and *CustomClaim2*. 
Hence if you don't mention them, they won't appear in access token.

Comment: I'm not using an API resource, just regular Identity resources